# Navigaton menu. Pressing buttons in the AS3 application without keyboard and mouse

Tags: actionscript-3

I am writing an application for Arduino on AS3. Keyboard and mouse are not provided.
There are a lot of buttons in the application. All of them can work with a keyboard and mouse. Management is planned to be carried out by changing the number taken from the array. The application accepts data only from Arduino.

If Data[5] ==100, FocusManager moves to the next button.
If Data[5] ==600, the button on which FocusManager is installed is clicked.

```
package
{
    import flash.events.*;
    import fl.managers.*;
    import flash.display.*;

    dynamic public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        public var fm:FocusManager;
        public var myBtnFocus:InteractiveObject; 
        public var myBtnName:String = "";
        public function Main()
        {
            addFrameScript(0, this.frame1);
            
            fm = new FocusManager(this);
            fm.setFocus( this ); //# manually set your button as default //# fm.setFocus( your button );
            
            this.myBtnFocus = fm.getFocus(); //# update the reference to know currently focused
            this.myBtnName = this.myBtnFocus.name; //# extract name from focused
            return;
        }// end function

        public function Rendering() : void
        {
            this.Connect.Status.text = this.Data[5]; // view arduino Data[5]
            if (this.Data[5] > 0)
            {
                if( ! Boolean(this.chkBtn))
                {   
                    if (this.Data[5] = 100) 
                    {
                        //# SOLVED - FocusManager go to next button (component)
                        this.myBtnFocus = fm.getNextFocusManagerComponent(); //# find it as next one
                        fm.setFocus( this.myBtnFocus ); //# then set as current selection (focused)
                        this.chkBtn = true;
                    }
                    /*
                    if (this.Data[5] = 150) {FocusManager go to the previous button (component)}
                    if (this.Data[5] = 200) {move FocusManager left (Arrow left)}
                    if (this.Data[5] = 300) {move FocusManager righ(Arrow right)}
                    if (this.Data[5] = 400) {move FocusManager up(Arrow up)}
                    if (this.Data[5] = 500) {move FocusManager dwn(Arrow dwn)}
                    if (this.Data[5] = 600) {SOLVED - click on the button on which the FocusManager is installed with a mouse click }
                    */
                }
            }
            else //# if the button is pressed and Data[5]==0, deleting variables
            {
                if( Boolean(this.chkBtn)) 
                {
                    delete this.chkBtn;
                }
            }
            return;
        }// end function
        
        public function onMouseClick (event:MouseEvent = null) :void        
        {
            if( event.currentTarget.name != null)
            { this.myBtnName = event.currentTarget.name; }
            trace( ">> Got Click ... Button name is : " + this.myBtnName );
        }
        
        public function onFocusedBtn (event:FocusEvent) :void 
        {
            trace (">> Got TAB ... Focus is now changed to : " + event.target.name)
        }
        
        function frame1()
        {
            this.Btn1.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, this.onMouseClick );
            this.Btn2.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, this.onMouseClick );
            this.Btn3.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, this.onMouseClick );
            
            //# Focus listener
            this.addEventListener( FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocusedBtn );
            return;
        }// end function
    }
}
```

How to implement if Data[5] ==150 - FocusManager goes to the previous button? How to change the position of the FocusManager to the left, up, down, right (simulating pressing keys on the keyboard)

Comment: **(1)** _"How to do this"_ is not a real question. What is your **expected** result? You just put a `myFunctions()` function with a random array... What does `move target left (Arrow left)` mean? If you're asking **how to simulate a keyboard press** in AS3 then you cannot. It's not designed for that. You can only make functions that respond to incoming keypress.

Comment: **(2)** _"I am writing an application for Arduino on AS3"_ is not clear.. Is your shown AS3 code supposed to be **sending to** or **receiving from** Arduino? Are you using something like Arduino's [Keyboard.write()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference.KeyboardWrite) to try control the AS3 app's menu options?

Comment: You noticed correctly, thank you. The array has been corrected. Is it possible to make an imitation of pressing a key on the keyboard by changing the number in a variable?

Comment: Is `this.Data[5] =` content coming from Arduino? So basically are you asking _"If I receive `200` **from Ardinuo**, how can I simulate `Arrow left` so AS3 does a move target left` function"_? If yes to both then i might have a solution for you. **PS**: Still not clear... Is your shown AS3 code supposed to be **sending to** or **receiving from** Arduino?

Comment: That's right, the answer to both questions is "yes". The application only accepts data on the Arduino.

Comment: Okay sticking to command `200`, do you have a function for what code happens whenever Arrow left is pressed? You need to run that function.

Comment: The code is not executed when the arrows are pressed. When you press TAB on the keyboard, the button is highlighted. You can move through the menu items only with the TAB button, but you can also use the arrows to move the focus of the button. The code is executed only when you click on some button in the application. The keyboard arrows only move the focus of the button. Clicking on the button in the application occurs by pressing the mouse button.

Comment: _"When you press TAB on the keyboard, the button is highlighted."_ Okay so apply the "button is highlighted" code logic in the function `doKey_TAB`. I upvoted your comment yesterday because it adds more info, but just the wording is not useful enough to write a better Answer. For example does "highlight" mean some MovieClip changes frames, or a Sprite changes its colour, or some "underline" shape moves to the menu option's X/Y position...? In Flash/AS3 a button is a **graphic** object and you don't cycle (focus) through graphics by pressing TAB.

Comment: "When you press TAB on the keyboard, the button is highlighted." - FocusManager is activated
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15bcTZxzIDu9HfCXWjJ-fau50jRg0nlNs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: See if this helps you [Work with FocusManager](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/components/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fd5.html). As a test put the code of `function showFocus(event:MouseEvent)` inside your own `doKey_TAB` (remove code from Mouse Event function and put into your custom function) then run the `doKey_TAB` function by Arduino codes. Does focus now change in the menu component?

Comment: **PS**: _"I tried to send the name of the button, but nothing worked"_ Did you give the button an **instance name**, that's what you must use to target a specific button. Try something like this `yourFocusManager.setFocus( Btn1 );`.

Comment: **PPS:** Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71785876/edit) with code that gives better idea of your app structure.  Mention if you are really using FocusManager in your code and how? After 3 days you changed your story to finally mention FocusManager, which I did not know you were using it. To me _"a menu"_ looks like [this example](https://codetea.com/content/images/2018/04/CSS-Staggered-Animation-Dropdown-Menu.gif) where to create that one you'd use **Sprite** or **MovieClip** (so your talking of pressing TAB for focus on menu options did not make sense previously).

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TWvKtn3pynil0A5s18bmgz8bvFCWDQUS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: "Does this tell you name of button that was clicked?... In function onBtn1(event:MouseEvent)` put trace( "btn name is : " + event.currentTarget.name );" -Yes, everything works fine, but I can't get the button into focus so that I can send this.

Comment: this.(event.currentTarget.name).dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK, true, false));

Comment: _"But the FocusManager does not appear in the application."_ it seems you **did not create a focusManager**. I don't even see `import fl.managers.FocusManager;` Where is your code for that part? What is the variable name of your focusManager? I can't fix your code without it.

Comment: "See if this helps you Work with FocusManager." - I read it, I can't apply it in my code. (((

Comment: I tried to call FocusManager, when I started the video I got error 1067. I removed it from the code because I can't run it. My knowledge is not enough. That's why I asked for help.

Comment: I don't have Flash here to test your AS3 code. I will try to edit it with focuManager code, you'll have to test it yourself, give me 5 minutes to write something...

Answer (score 0):

To test example code below..

- To simulate "TAB", 
  send from Arduino a code `100` each time to change the selected button's index.
- To simulate "ENTER" or "CLICK", 
  send from Arduino a code `600` to know which button was clicked.

For example to simulate clicking on btn2 you send Data 3 times with: `100` --> `100` --> `600`

Try something like this:

```
//# index of the button that was selected via keypress TAB or mouse Click
public var index_OfSelected :uint = 0;

//# for handling keyboard pressing
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);

//# for where/whenever you receive data from Arduino
process_Data ( this.Data ); //run function with Arduino "Data" as function input
    
public function process_Data ( inData :Array ) :void
{
    //# we'll reference the function's input as "inData"...
    
    if (inData[5] = 100) doKey_TAB();       //# selected target my buttons (TAB)
    if (inData[5] = 200) doKey_left();      //# move target left (Arrow left)
    if (inData[5] = 300) doKey_right();     //# move target right (Arrow right)
    if (inData[5] = 400) doKey_up();        //# move target up (Arrow up)
    if (inData[5] = 500) doKey_down();      //# move target down (Arrow down)
    if (inData[5] = 600) doKey_Enter();     //# enter (mouse click)
    
    //return; //# cannot return anything if return type is ":void"
}

function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.TAB) { doKey_TAB(); }
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER) { doKey_Enter(); }
}

function doKey_TAB () :void
{
    //# do TAB stuff/code here...
    //# eg: highlight a selected button or menu option...
    
    index_OfSelected++;
    
    //# reset number if pressing TAB increases higher than 15 items
    if( index_OfSelected > 15) { index_OfSelected = 1; }
    
    trace(">> Pressed TAB : current button is : Btn" + String( index_OfSelected ) );
    
}

function doKey_Enter () :void
{
    //# do Enter stuff/code here...
    trace(">> Pressed ENTER or CLICK : current button is : Btn" + String( index_OfSelected ) );
}

public function onBtn1(event:MouseEvent) : void        
{
    index_OfSelected = 1; doKey_Enter();    
}

public function onBtn2(event:MouseEvent) : void        
{
    index_OfSelected = 2; doKey_Enter();    
}

public function onBtn15(event:MouseEvent) : void        
{
    index_OfSelected = 15; doKey_Enter();   
}

function frame1()
{
    this.Btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.onBtn1); //# index = 1
    this.Btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.onBtn2); //# index = 2
    this.Btn15.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.onBtn15); //# index = 15
    
    //return; //# should Error since it does not seem to return anything...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your shown, you can try something like below to use [focusManager](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/managers/FocusManager.html).

Code is untested (no AS3 compiler here).

```
package
{
    //# put imports here
    
    import fl.managers.FocusManager;

    dynamic public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        //# put vars here (as public or private or static ... etc)
        
        public var fm:FocusManager;
        
        //# reference to the selected button object
        public var myBtnComponent:InteractiveObject; 
        public var myBtnName :String = "";
        
        //# /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //# Main code and supporting functions...
        //# /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        public function Main()
        {
            fm = new FocusManager(this);
            addFrameScript(0, this.frame1);
            
            //# use one of these to set a default (starting) selection...
            fm.setFocus( btn1 ); //# try to manually set btn1 as default?
            fm.defaultButton( btn1 ); //# or maybe this works better?
            
            myBtnComponent = fm.getFocus(); //# update the reference to know currently focused
            myBtnName = myBtnComponent.name; //# extract name from focused
        }

        public function Rendering() : void
        {
            //# cast numbers to String for using as text
            this.Connect.Status.text = String( this.Data[5] ); // view arduino Data[5]
            
            if (this.Data[5] > 0)
            {
                if( ! Boolean(this.chkBtn))
                {   
                    
                    //# press Enter
                    if ( (this.Data[5] == 600) || (this.Data[5] == "600") )
                    {
                        //# set name manually because it's not an Event
                        //# meaning you cannot check with: event.currentTargetname
                        
                        myBtnName = myBtnComponent.name; //# extract name from focused
                        
                        doKey_Enter(); //# simulate ENTER press
                        
                    }   
                    
                    //# press TAB
                    if ( (this.Data[5] == 100) || (this.Data[5] == "100") )
                    {
                        //# TAB = go to next button (component)
                        myBtnComponent = fm.getNextFocusManagerComponent(); //# find it as next one
                        fm.setFocus( myBtnComponent ); //# then set as current selection (focused)
                        
                    }               
                    
                    //# this needs fixing ...
                    if (this.Data[5] == 200)
                    {   
                        /*
                        var event:KeyboardEvent = new KeyboardEvent(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN);
                        event.keyCode = keyCode.LEFT;
                        dispatchEvent(event);
                        this.chkBtn = true;
                        */
                        
                        //move FocusManager left (Arrow left),then the keyboard button with the left arrow should be pressed. This will be "KEY_DOWN".                    
                        
                        //# just manually run the "onDown" keyboard function
                        onDown();
                        
                    }
                    
                    /*
                    if (this.Data[5] = 300) {move target righ(Arrow right)}
                    if (this.Data[5] = 400) {move target up(Arrow up)}
                    if (this.Data[5] = 500) {move target dwn(Arrow dwn)}
                    if (this.Data[5] = 600) {click on the button on which the FocusManager is installed with a mouse click  }
                    */
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                if( Boolean(this.chkBtn)) 
                {
                    /*
                    var event:KeyboardEvent = new KeyboardEvent(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP);
                    event.keyCode = which was pressed;
                    dispatchEvent(event);
                    delete this.chkBtn;
                    */
                    
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        public function onDown (e:KeyboardEvent = null) :void 
        {
            
            var myKeyCode :int = -1; //# maybe create as public var (at top of code)
            
            if( e.keyCode != null ) 
            { myKeyCode = e.keyCode; trace("key code is : " + myKeyCode ); }
            
            //# key Left
            if ( (this.Data[5] == 200) || (myKeyCode == 37) || (myKeyCode == "LEFT") )
            {   
                //# do left key stuff or run some function...
            }
        }
        
        public function onUp (e:KeyboardEvent = null) :void 
        {
            if( e.keyCode != null ) { trace(e.keyCode + " UP"); }
        }

        public function onMouseClick (event:MouseEvent = null) :void        
        {
            if( event.currentTarget.name != null)
            { myBtnName = event.currentTarget.name; }
            
            trace( ">> Got Click ... Button name is : " + myBtnName );
            
            fm.setFocus( myBtnComponent );
            doKey_Enter();
        }
        
        public function onFocusedBtn (event:FocusEvent) :void 
        {
            trace(">> Got TAB ... Focus is now changed to : " + event.target.name);
        }
        
        function doKey_Enter () :void
        {
            //# do Enter stuff/code here...
            
            trace(">> Got ENTER ... current Button is : " + myBtnName );
            
            if( myBtnName == "Btn1" ) { do_Btn1_stuff(); }
            if( myBtnName == "Btn2" ) { do_Btn2_stuff(); }
            
        }
        
        function do_Btn1_stuff () :void
        {
            //# code for whatever task happens 
            //# whenever your button 1 is actually clicked or Enter pressed...
            //# example: play some sound if app is like a virtual music instrument
            
            trace(">> Got RUN FUNCTION ... doing Btn1 stuff here ... " );
            
        }
        
        function do_Btn2_stuff () :void
        {
            //# code for button 2 when pressed or clicked
            trace(">> Got RUN FUNCTION ... doing Btn2 stuff here ... " );
        }
        
        function frame1()
        {
            this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onUp);
            this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onDown);
            
            //Btn1.name = "Btn1"; //# if needed for updating variable: myBtnName ...
            
            Btn1.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, onMouseClick );
            Btn1.addEventListener( FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocusedBtn );
                
            Btn2.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, onMouseClick );
            Btn2.addEventListener( FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocusedBtn );
            
            Btn15.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, onMouseClick );
            Btn15.addEventListener( FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocusedBtn );
        }

    } //end Class Main
    
} //end Package
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You've been very helpful. I realized where I made a mistake in FocusManager. I assigned myBtnName:Button, so I got an error))) TAB now works as I need it. But I still haven't figured out how to press a button on the keyboard using just the code? I tried to send an event.keyCode = keyCode.LEFT, and I get error 1120.

Comment: To handle a code like `200` you could just manually run the `onDown()` function. You will get an **undefined error** because `200` is a number not a keyboard event (which **AS3 receives ONLY from the Operating System**, like Windows). Add an **If/Else** to check for keycode existence (it won't exist if Arduino sends a number, but it will exist if you use a keyboard). Since `200` is equal to keycode `37` (or `LEFT`) just check for either Arduino number **or** (by using `||`) event keycode. You will have one or other (as `200 || "LEFT"`).

Comment: how instead of "doKey_Enter();" use "(myBtnName).dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK, true, false));"?

Comment: this[myBtnName].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK, true, false)); - works. I'll try how it works in the application, I'll write about the results. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: What would that achieve that you can't already just do in `doKey_Enter`? When you click a button (or send the `600` code), does `trace` not tell you which button is currently focused? Pressing ENTER on a focused button is same thing as clicking the focused button. What is the real problem here? Why care about mouse Click event if you said in your Question that _"Keyboard and Mouse are not provided"_. Just send signals to select a button and signal to press it.

Comment: that's right, the keyboard and mouse are not provided. As I have already said, this is a program for a car, or rather for a truck. the application displays the readings of sensors, control lamps, and much more. While debugging and calibrating sensors, I can connect a mouse. If you do control from the keyboard, then the mouse does not work. In the operating mode, the driver, by controlling the buttons from the remote control, can view sensors, fuel and much more. Fixed buttons in the menu 15. Each button has another menu, it has 10 MovieClip, which has 2 more buttons. A total of 300 buttons.

Comment: You have helped me very well. I'll try to show you the application by video. I would also like to implement arrows (37,38,39,40).

Comment: how can I contact you? my mail zh25lt@gmail.com

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GlJEu5n-PgrO7rkBwJx9i5sqSz2Tmkdu/view?usp=sharing